# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, webjob, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have created a new project in VS 2017 using `Azure Webjobs ( .NET Framework )` template.

[image]

After that I have included valid values for AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage in App.config file.

After running the sample I am getting below error message.

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request
```

Any idea whats missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage offers several types of storage accounts. It seems that you are using the Blob storage account.(I encountered the same issue if I use this type) You need to use general-purpose v2 accounts instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use MyException.ToString(), maybe you'll find somewhere in there that says: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.

Then you can change your container name from Test1 to test1 because it doesn't like uppercase characters.